# phonegap remove all permission except INTERNET

Tags: cordova, permissions

I created a phonegap android app (very simple app) but when I publish it to Google it shows this:

My app does not required ANY of these, how can I remove it from the .apk.

I look everywhere on stack over flow and I can't find config.xml, the manifest looks like this:

@^@^@"^@^@^@^H^@^@^C"^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^X^@^@^@ÿ
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@
 ^@^@^@#^@^@^@^H^@^@^C#^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^Y^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^Z^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@  ^@^@^@$^@^@^@^H^@^@^C$^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^Z^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^[^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@  ^@^@^@%^@^@^@^H^@^@^C%^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^[^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^\^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@  @^@^@&^@^@^@^H^@^@^C&^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^\^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^]^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@  ^@^@^@'^@^@^@^H^@^@^C'^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^]^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^^^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^T^@^T^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^T^@^@^@  ^@^@^@(^@^@^@^H^@^@^C(^@^@^@^C^A^P^@^X^@^@^@^^^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^@^@^@^B^A^P^@8^@^@^@^_^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ^[^

Where can I change these permissions in phonegap. I want to only have INTERNET. I am using the website

[image: permisssions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it (It's a pain but it's working):

1) download your apk from build.phonegap.com

2) decode apk:

```
$ apktool decode my-app.apk
```

3) edit "AndroidManifest.xml":

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" [...]
```

4) rebuild apk:

```
$ apktool build my-app/
```

5) sign apk:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /path-to-your--release-key.keystore my-app/dist/my-app.apk your-alias
```

6) zipalign apk (needed for market release):

```
$ zipalign 4 my-app/dist/my-app.apk my-app/dist/my-app-for-market.apk
```

Comment: Did you add any permissions in your config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should specify that you are using phonegap build and not creating app using the sdk (when you use local sdk, you have full access to androidmanifest.xml and any config file)

In phonegap prior to version 3.0, all plugins were included by default and so all permissions were needed.

Starting with verison 3.0, a new project contains no plugin and requires no autorisation, needed permissions are added only when you install a plugin that needs it.